Why does the first block of the epoch include all the L2 deposits that happened in the L1 block?
From Optimism docs:

Transactions get to the sequencer in two ways:

Transactions submitted on L1 (called deposits) are included in the chain in the appropriate L2 block. Every L2 block is identified by the "epoch" (the L1 block to which it corresponds, which typically has happened a few minutes before the L2 block) and its serial number within that epoch. The first block of the epoch includes all the deposits that happened in the L1 block to which it corresponds.


Why is that?
I would have expected the first block of an epoch to contain all the deposits of the previous epoch.

As discussed here, that's not the Beacon Chain epoch, but a bespoke L2 epoch introduced by OP Stack.
Optimism's spec website fleshes this out:

The rollup chain is subdivided into epochs. There is a 1:1 correspondence between L1 block numbers and epoch numbers.
For L1 block number n, there is a corresponding rollup epoch n which can only be derived after a sequencing window worth of blocks has passed, i.e. after L1 block number n + SEQUENCING_WINDOW_SIZE is added to the L1 chain.

